# Google Sheets Insert Cell Values into another Cell using formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-workspace

So, I am looking to insert two cell values into one cell, one following the other.
For the following example see the Image below.[image: Spreadsheet]

I want to put a Formula in C such that the formula would result in ab
I am aware you can set one cell equal to another just by =A1, but I am looking to put both in at the same time. Something like =(=A1)(=B1),but that actually works, because this just returns the general "Formula Parse Error".

Comment: The cell values are text, so you’re not trying to perform mathematical addition. There are a bunch of formulas for joining text, but you could also try “=A1&B1”

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Use that in cell `C1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(,,A1,B1)
```

**Output:**

[image: example]

**References:**

[TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)